# How can I print a line that updates itself but in 3 different lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, format

Okay, I find a little bit strange my question, but I'll try to explain the best I can here.

I know that if I use `\r` for printing I can get a line printing over itself over and over again.
For example, if I want to know the % of a process I could do:

```
print("\rProgress {}%".format(percentage),end="")
```

And that will print all the progress in only 1 line. But what if the line that I'm trying to print is larger? How can I achieve something like this:

Iteration 1:

```
Progres A 0.0%
Progres B 0.0%
Progres C 0.0%
```

Iteration 2:

```
Progres A 1.0%
Progres B 1.0%
Progres C 1.0%
```

And so on...

I have tried something like:

```
for _ in range(5):
   print("""\rhello
   {}""".format(i),end="")
```

but the output is:

```
hello
hello  0
hello  1
hello  2
hello  3
       4
```

Also tried other combinations, but the output is similar.

For the last example, the desired output would be 2 lines, having the first one with `hello` and the second one with the corresponding `_` depending on each timestep.

Iteration 1:

```
hello
0
```

Iteration 2:

```
hello
1
```

Iteration 3:

```
hello
2
```

All the way up to the last iteration, that would be:

```
hello
4
```

EDIT: The reason why I'm trying to do this is because the string is too large and I want to break it down because it does not fit well neither in the actual cell or the current output.

The string looks like:

```
Iteration 1: Progress: xx.xx%, current step/total steps: cs/ts, bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
```

I would like to break it in something like this:

```
Iteration 1:
Progress: xx.xx%
current step/total steps: cs/ts
bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla
```

Comment: This needs a more advanced library like "curses".

Comment: And if you making a dedicated progress bar i would use tkinter, its pretty easy

Answer (score 0):

Use '\n' to break the line, for example

```
print ("\rProgress {0}\nProgress{1}\nProgress{2}".format(percentageA, percentageB, percentageC ), end=" ")
```

This will make the 3 lines in 1 print function

Comment: Hi @12ksins, indeed it will print 3 lines, but the thing is that the string I'm trying to print is too large, so I want to cut it.

The string looks like:
"Iteration 1: Progress: xx.xx%, current step/total steps: cs/ts, bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla".